# Laptop Monitor Resolution

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

I have a question about adjusting a laptop resolution.  My work laptop is a Dell latitude 5490.

When I am using the laptop normally, the maximum resolution for the display is 1366x768 and I can't go any higher than that.  Normally I would say that is just the limit and I am stuck. I have found though, that if I connect an external display to the laptop, and select to mirror the display, the laptop display will mirror the higher resolution of the external monitor. If I connect a 1080p monitor to the laptop, the internal display scales and reports that it is running at 1920x1080.

I'm sure this isn't natively displayed, but the result of something like "Virtual Super Resolution" which is available through AMD catalyst.  The image clarity isn't as good as using the native resolution, but at times thats ok.

What I would like to do, is enabling the resolution without having to connect an external display, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.  Does anyone have any idea how to force this behavior without attaching an external display.

Comment: You would need to get a way to add custom resolutions to your windows and find out what the resolution becomes when you set it to 1920x1080 and add that (the timings etc)

Comment: That is the max resolution for the built in display, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Moab not entirely true. If the display supports higher resolutions with weird timings, it will work if they are added manually.

Comment: Something is causing the internal display to go from 1366x768 to 1920x1080p when I connect an external monitor.  Like I said, it is probably via super sampling or some other artificial method and not truly displaying 1080p, but for what I am doing the extra screen space is worth the decreased sharpness